# Create class to return char array

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to create a class in C++ that helps me to manipulate a char array. How can I make this the right way?

1 - Create the char array using the provided size

2 - Return the char array in getArray()

```
class ByteArray {
public:
    ByteArray(int size) {
        array_.resize(size);
    }

    const char* getArray() { return array_; }

private:
    char array_[];
};
```

Comment: maybe take a look at std::vector

Comment: What do you need the class to do? Can't you just use a container such as `std::vector<char>` and algorithms?

Comment: @juanchopanza : he probably want's to do it as an exercise.

Comment: It is part of a protocol to communicate with other applications in other languages. I'm trying to write a class to manipulate binary data like Actionscript 3 ByteArray, to be easier to other programmers read. It communicates with Adobe Air applications and Node.js applications. Thanks all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the most optimal version that I found.

```
class ByteArray {
public:
    ByteArray(int size) {
        array_ = (char*)malloc(size);
    }

    ~ByteArray() {
        free(array_);
        array_ = NULL;
    }

    const char * getArray() { return array_; }

private:
    char * array_;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use std::vector;

```
 class ByteArray {
    public:
        ByteArray(int size) {
            array_.reserve(size);
        }

        const char* getArray() { return array_.data(); }

    private:
        std::vector<char> array_;
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this probably

```
class ByteArray {
public:
    ByteArray(int size) {
        delete[] array_;
        array_ = new char[size];
    }

    const char* getArray() { return array_; }

private:
    char *array_;
};
```

You cannot use an array with no size, instead you can dynamically allocate it.

Comment: You will need to do something to not leak memory.

Comment: yeah, probably delete the array in the destructor, and put some guard not to delete a null array the first time.

Comment: This is ok, but using vector<char> like Alexis suggested is better to me. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to guard against deleting a null pointer. But you would have to do something about copy and assignment.

Comment: @GeoAoe First I used the vector<char>, but latter I tried something like your answer and it is much faster. Check my own answer.